# Why aren't both of my views being displayed?

Tags: android, layout

So I've been trying to figure out layouts and using the layout inflater, but I'm running into some issues. I have two relative xml layout files, the one xml file has two textViews, an editText field, and a spinner object:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/goalNameView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:text="@string/goalName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/goal_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/goalNameView"
    android:hint="@string/editText"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/goalTasksView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/goal_tasks"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/goal_tasks"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/goalNameView"
    android:text="@string/goalTasks" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/goal_tasks"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/goalTasksView"
    android:layout_marginTop="51dp" />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

the other xml file has one textView and one editText field:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/tView"
 >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/taskNameField"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/taskNameView"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/editText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/taskNameView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/taskNameField"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/taskNameField"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@string/taskName"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm trying to patch the two layouts together with a third xml file (main.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/theMain"
>

<include android:id="@id/mainLayout" layout="@layout/activity_goal_keeper"  />



</LinearLayout>
```

The way I'm looking to have the layout work is to display the first layout (@id/firstLayout) and then the second layout (@id/tView) directly beneath it. I've read that I need to implement the layouts on a LinearLayout to achieve this which is why I have the third layout (@id/theMain).

As you can see I have an include statement for @id/firstLayout, but I don't have an include statement for @id/tView because I'm trying to inflate multiple versions of @id/tView via my main activity:

```
 public class GoalKeeperActivity extends Activity implements       AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
 public Integer[] items= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_goal_keeper);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Spinner numOfTasks=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.goal_tasks);
    numOfTasks.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    ArrayAdapter<Integer> aa = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);

    aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    numOfTasks.setAdapter(aa);

    ViewGroup item = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.theMain);

    for(int i=0; i<3;i++)
    {
      View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tasks_view, item, false);
      child.setId(i);
      item.addView(child);

    }
```

My problem is that @firstLayout displays properly, but @tView doesn't show up at all. Can someone please explain what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might it have to do with your open `TextView` tag? (It's the one all in black in your post above.)

Comment: @Eric - Thanks, I must have deleted that by accident, it's just a typo in the question. I'll edit the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it was simply an issue of setting the "android:layout_height" attribute equal to wrap_content on the @id/tView xml file. Silly little mistakes...